# Failed to copy local file to the k8s container of the keycloak by using kubectl cp

Tags: docker, kubernetes, keycloak, kubectl

This is what my commend looks like

```
kubectl cp /Users/Documents/keycloak-deployment/import/realm-export-sdp.json sdp-steve/keycloak-7458697ddb-tbzp8:/tmp
```

And I got the error message as below:

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:235: starting container process caused "exec: \"tar\": executable file not found in $PATH"

error: Internal error occurred: error executing command in container: read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer
```

Does anyone know how to handle this error? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your container image must have `tar` binary present for running `kubectl cp` subcommand.  As a result, you are getting the following error:

```
 "exec: \"tar\": executable file not found in $PATH
```

See the below snippet:

```
kubectl cp --help
Copy files and directories to and from containers.

Examples:
  # !!!Important Note!!!
  # Requires that the 'tar' binary is present in your container
  # image.  If 'tar' is not present, 'kubectl cp' will fail.
  #
  # For advanced use cases, such as symlinks, wildcard expansion or
  # file mode preservation, consider using 'kubectl exec'.
```

You may check [this](https://gist.github.com/tallclair/9217e2694b5fdf27b55d6bd1fda01b53) page showing why `tar` is needed.